# Why I need to include block_cache_key.h and block.h before block_cache.h in the following example?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Usually we would use standard type as key and value for `std::unordered_map<key, value>`. But now I need to customize my own key and value class.

Key class is defined in `block_cache_key.h` as following:

```
#ifndef BLOCK_CACHE_KEY_H_
#define BLOCK_CACHE_KEY_H_

#include <functional>

namespace wcg{
class BlockCacheKey{
public:
    BlockCacheKey(const std::string &name, int64_t offset) : name_(name), offset_(offset) {}

    bool operator==(const BlockCacheKey &other) const{
        return offset_ == other.offset_ && name_ == other.name_;
    }

    const std::string &name() const{
        return name_;
    }

    const int64_t offset() const{
        return offset_;
    }

    std::string to_string() const{
        return name_ + "_" + std::to_string(offset_);
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
    int64_t offset_;
};
}

namespace std{
    template <>
    class hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey>{
    public:
        size_t operator()(const wcg::BlockCacheKey &key) const{
            return std::hash<std::string>()(key.name()) ^ (std::hash<int64_t>()(key.offset()));
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

Value class is defined in `block.h` as following:

```
#ifndef BLOCK_H_
#define BLOCK_H_

namespace wcg{
class Block{
public:
    Block() {}
};
}

#endif
```

And the class which use `std::unorded_map` is defined in `block_cache.h` as following:

```
#ifndef BLOCK_CACHE_H_
#define BLOCK_CACHE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace wcg{

class BlockCacheKey;
class Block;

class BlockCache{
public:
    BlockCache() : count_(0) {
        std::cout << "initial stats: " << to_string() << std::endl;
    }

    ~BlockCache(){
        std::cout << "final stats: " << to_string() << std::endl;
    }

    void CacheBlock(const BlockCacheKey &key, std::shared_ptr<Block> block){
        std::cout << "cache put: " << key.to_string() << std::endl;
        map_[key] = block;
        count_++;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Block> GetBlock(const BlockCacheKey &key){
        auto pos = map_.find(key);
        if(pos != map_.end()){
            std::cout << "cache get: " << key.to_string() << std::endl;
            return pos->second;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::string to_string() const{
        return "block count: " + std::to_string(count_);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<BlockCacheKey, std::shared_ptr<Block>> map_;
    int count_;
};
}

#endif
```

The main function is defined in `main.cpp` as following:

```
#include <memory>

#include "block_cache_key.h"
#include "block.h"
#include "block_cache.h"

// g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall main.cpp

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    wcg::BlockCache bc;
    return 0;
}
```

When `#include "block_cache.h"` is at last, the compilation is OK. But when `#include "block_cache.h"` is before `#include "block_cache_key.h"` and    `#include "block.h"`, the compilation would fail and the error message is very ugly, very hard to understand.

What I already know, `std::unordered_map` is a template.
When GCC compiles, it will first preprocess the include part, that is unfold them all.
That gives me the impression that the include order would not be a question.

**Last thing to note, I do not want to include `block_cache_key.h` and `block.h` in `block_cache.h`**

Part of the compilation error message:
(entire error message is in https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VyrWKCTG4q/)

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/unordered_map:47,
                 from block_cache.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >':
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:143:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> > >'
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:154:31:   required from 'struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> > > >'
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_map.h:103:66:   required from 'class std::unordered_map<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::shared_ptr<wcg::Block> >'
block_cache.h:50:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:87:34: error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey>) (const wcg::BlockCacheKey&)'
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/move.h:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:62,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> > > >':
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_map.h:103:66:   required from 'class std::unordered_map<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::shared_ptr<wcg::Block> >'
block_cache.h:50:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:154:31: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> > >'
     : public __bool_constant<!bool(_Pp::value)>
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/unordered_map:48:0,
                 from block_cache.h:13,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_map.h: In instantiation of 'class std::unordered_map<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::shared_ptr<wcg::Block> >':
block_cache.h:50:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_map.h:103:66: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> > > >'
       typedef __umap_hashtable<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>  _Hashtable;
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unordered_map.h:110:45: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey, std::hash<wcg::BlockCacheKey> > > >'
       typedef typename _Hashtable::key_type key_type;
```

Comment: paste the error message in the question

Comment: One of the fundamental skills in programming is reading and understanding compiler diagnostics. Yes, they can be hard to understand; that doesn't mean you should ignore what they say. Usually, for template problems, the diagnostic is a long list of things, one of which is marked "error"; that's the key.

Comment: Just guessing, but two of these headers use `std::string` but neither header includes the appropriate header. It's possible that the definition of `std::string` comes in from another standard header, and if that's what's happening, the order of the `#include` directives could affect whether that definition is seen in all the places where it's needed. The solution, of course, is to add `#include <string>` to the headers that use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at `BlockCache.h`. You promise the compiler that `Block` and `BlockCacheKey` exist and will be defined eventually - at this point they are **incomplete types**. This is ok and works well as long as you do not use them in a way that requires them to be **complete**: Forming references, pointers or even `std::shared_ptr`s to incomplete types is fine. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) for a list of things you must not do with them.

You are violating this by using `BlockCacheKey` (and `Block`) in `std::unordered_map<BlockCacheKey, std::shared_ptr<Block>>` - to instantiate the `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>` template (which is necessary to declare a member of that type), the `Key` and `Value` types must be complete.

Imagine that `sizeof(std::unordered_map<Key, Value>)` depended on `sizeof(Key)` (which would be within its rights). With only a forward declaration of `Key`, `sizeof(Key)` would be unknown, thus `sizeof(std::unordered_map<Key, Value>)` would be unknown, thus the size of your `BlockCache` would be unknown (even after you defined it!). The compiler cannot work with that, which is why you're not allowed to do it.

> Last thing to note, I do not want to include block_cache_key.h and block.h in block_cache.h

This is not possible (without requiring funky inclusion orders by users as you have observed). To instantiate `std::map<BlockCacheKey, Whatever>`, the definition of `BlockCacheKey` must be known, which you only get from including its header. I do believe the same is true for `Block` in the `std::shared_ptr<Block>` type you intend to use as value type for the map.